# JAXB: Replase namespase after marshalling

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have xsd schemas. Using jaxb2-maven-plugin gotted Java objects and after init i doing marshaling to xml.
All work, i get xml file. But in this file namespase in view "ns#". At the same time, my xsd file contains namespaces of the form "com: pkg: and etc".Please tell me how and at what point is the conversion of the namespace.

```
xsd ecxample: 
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:com="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Common/2.1.1"
        xmlns:pkg="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Package/2.1.1"
        xmlns="urn://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/services/import- 
charges/2.1.1"
        targetNamespace="urn://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/services/import-charges/2.1.1"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

xml result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns7:ImportChargesRequest 
xmlns="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Charge/2.1.1" 
xmlns:ns2="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Common/2.1.1" 
xmlns:ns3="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Organization/2.1.1" 
xmlns:ns4="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Package/2.1.1" 
xmlns:ns5="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Payment/2.1.1" 
xmlns:ns6="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Refund/2.1.1" 
xmlns:ns7="urn://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/services/import- 
charges/2.1.1" Id="1" timestamp="2019-06-05T13:46:20.747+07:00" 
senderIdentifier="1" senderRole="TEST">
```

marshaling:

```
    try {
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(elem, os);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    } finally {
        if (osw != null) {
            osw.close();
        }
```

XML is formed. But I don't understand why the namespace in xml changes compared to xsd.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={
            @XmlNs(prefix="pkg", namespaceURI="http://roskazna.ru/gisgmp/xsd/Package/2.1.1"),
    }
```

).